# Similarity transformation of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices

I'm self studying linear algebra and I got stuck with one doubt.

I've a transformation $T$ represented by an orthogonal  matrix $A$ , so $A^TA=I$. This transformation leaves norm unchanged.

I do a basis change using a matrix $B$ which isn't orthogonal  , then the form of the transformation changes to $B^{-1}AB$ in the new basis( A similarity transformation).

Since we only changed our representation of the transformation $T$ then transformation $B^{-1}AB$ should also leave norm unchanged which means that $B^{-1}AB$ should be orthogonal.

Therefore $B^{-1}AB$.${{[B^{-1}AB}}]^T=I$.

This suggests that $B^TB=I$ which means it is orthogonal, but that is a contradiction.

Can anyone tell me if what I did wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: "Since we only changed our representation of the transformation $T$ then...": well, no.

Comment: Why should change of basis affect the transformation?

Comment: You probably make a false idea of a change of basis. In general it is not a rigid transformation. Think of the change from $(1,0),(0,1)$ to $(1,0),(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A transformation $\mathscr{A}$ is orthogonal iff its matrix representation is orthogonal with respect to an standard orthogonal basis. And the transition matrix between two standard orthogonal bases must be orthogonal.

$B_1=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, $B_2=\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ are two standard orthogonal bases. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are representations of $\mathscr{A}$ with respect to  $B_1,B_2$. Then $A_1,A_2$ are orthogonal matrices.
$$
\mathscr{A}(e_i)=\text{the $i$th colume of $A_1$};\;\;\mathscr{A}(f_i)=\text{the $i$th colume of $A_2$}
$$
If $P$ is the transition matrix between $B_1$ and $B_2$(  that is $(e_1,\dots,e_n)=(f_1,\dots,f_n)P$), then $P$ is orthogonal.

Comment: So you mean that B has to be orthogonal?

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe you can read your textbook again and try to figure out the relation between matrices and transformations. Hope I can help you! : )

Comment: Basically in a non standard basis the orthogonal transformation may not be represented by an orthogonal matrix.